# Hindi Font not supporting in Kendo UI Angular PDF Export

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I'm facing an issue with Kendo UI Angular while exporting content to PDF, specifically when using Hindi fonts. The PDF export works fine, but the Hindi characters are not displayed correctly.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { products } from './products';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button kendo-button (click)="pdf.saveAs('table.pdf')">
      Save As PDF...
    </button>
    <kendo-pdf-export #pdf paperSize="A4" margin="2cm" [repeatHeaders]="true">
      <div>header info 1</div>
      <div class="pdf-export-only">अधिकारों</div>
      <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="products">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name"></kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
    </kendo-pdf-export>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./pdf-styles.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public products: any[] = products;
}
```

- I have already tried using different fonts that support Hindi characters.
- I have included the necessary font files in my project.
- I have configured Kendo PDF export to use the correct font.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Kendo UI Angular PDF export and Hindi fonts? If so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Where did you include the fonts required? Afaik, they need to be declared somewhere but I can't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Cuzy

.pdf-export-only{
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}